# INSERT ON DUPLICATE from another table

Tags: mysql

I have read a lot before asking but since I am a noob eith MYSQL the answers were a bit confusing to me so let me try to put my own question and see if someone can help.

I have a table called "parse" and this table has data I need to throw into another table called "updates".

Ok, so "updates" is created but now I have updated the data from parse (that is the source of the data) and both tables have a unique ID called "link".

I was planning to run "INSERT ON DUPLICATE" but not sure how to do it. So basically, the field "link" is the unique ID that needs to remain the same in both tables, but the rest will update like price for example in the table "updates".

Can you guide me on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: so what I am looking for? Maybe UPDATE ON DUPLICATE?

Comment: I deleted my initial comment, I didn't read your question fully.

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` defintiion of `updates` and `parse`?

Comment: Try ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as explained by @Dai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate statement would have this form:

```
INSERT INTO destination (
    -- List columns in `destination` here.
)
SELECT
    -- List columns from `source` here. Ensure they correspond to the columns listed for `destination` exactly otherwise you'll get an error (or worse: unintentional data corruption).
FROM
    source
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -- List both `destination` and `source` columns again here, excluding immutable and key columns. Refer to the source column via `VALUES()`.
```

In your case, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO "updates" (
    link, /* PK */
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d
)
SELECT
    link,
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d
FROM
    "parse"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    a = VALUES(a),
    b = VALUES(b),
    c = VALUES(c),
    d = VALUES(d);
```

Comment: Nice thank you so much ! Does this sound correct?

INSERT INTO "updates" (Product, Price, Link
    
)
SELECT
 Product, Price, Link
FROM
    "parse"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    Product = VALUES(Product),
    Price = VALUES(Price);

Comment: Yes that looks fine.